# php codeigniter copy&paste doesnt work

Tags: php, function, codeigniter, copy-paste

This is very strange and incredible

in codeigniter model the content of two function is the same

```
function one(){ $query=the same query;}
function two(){ $query=the same query;}
```

I copy the content of first function in the second function but the query is made only in function one !

the content is the same ! only the name of the function is different (obviously)

this is strange and i lost a lot of time to solve the error

someone can help me

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Its possible your function is inside another function. Or you are reusing variables incorrectly. Without the model file and the call you make from the controller there is not enough information to give you a fix without speculation.

Comment: the function isnt in another function @Joseph

Comment: Yep, we definitely need to see more code for a more complete analysis.

Comment: @SgtAJ there is a simple query ! its incredible :(

Comment: post both functions here.